# Finding letters that are near, exact or not in a user input string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am currently developing a small modified version of Hangman in Rails for children. The game starts by randomly generating a word from a text file and the user has to guess the word by entering a four letter word. Each word is the split by each character for example "r", "e", "a", "l" and returns a message on how they are to the word.

Random Generated word is "real"

Input 
   `rlax`

Output
    `Correct, Close, Correct, Incorrect`

I have tried other things which I have found online but haven't worked and I am fairly new to Ruby and Rails. Hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction.

Here is some code

```
def letterCheck(lookAtLetter)   
  lookAHead = lookAtLetter =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ 
end 

def displayWord         
  $ranWordBool.each_index do |i|        
      if($ranWordBool[i])           
          print $ranWordArray[i]        
          $isWin += 1                   
      else
          print "_"     
      end               
  end           
end 

def gameLoop            
  turns = 10            
  turnsLeft = 0     
  lettersUsed = []  
  while(turnsLeft < turns)      
     $isWin = 0                 
     displayWord                    

     if($isWin == $ranWordBool.length)          
       system "cls"                         
       puts "1: Quit"                           
       puts "The word is #{$ranWord} and You Win"   
       puts "Press any key to continue"     
       return               
     end            

     print "\n" + "Words Used: "            
     lettersUsed.each_index do |looper|     
     print " #{lettersUsed[looper]} "   
     end                    
     puts "\n" + "Turns left: #{turns - turnsLeft}" 

     puts "Enter a word"        
     input = gets.chomp         
     system "cls"   

     if(input.length != 4)  
       puts "Please enter 4 lettered word"
     elsif(letterCheck(input))  
       if(lettersUsed.include?(input))  
         puts "#{input} already choosen"    
         elsif($ranWordArray.include?(input))
           puts "Close"
           $ranWordArray.each_index do |i|  
             if(input == $ranWordArray[i])
               $ranWordBool[i] = true   
             end    
             if($ranWordBool[i] = true)
               puts "Correct"
             else
               puts "Incorrect"
             end
           end          
          else
            lettersUsed << input        
            turnsLeft += 1          
          end                   
          else
            puts "Not a letter"     
          end                       
        end                         
        puts "You lose"             
        puts "The word was #{$ranWord}"     
        puts "Press any key to continue"    
      end           

      words = []            
      File.foreach('words.txt') do |line|       
      words << line.chomp               
      end           

      while(true)
        $ranWord = words[rand(words.length) + 1]    
        $ranWordArray = $ranWord.chars          
        $ranWordBool = []                           
        $ranWordArray.each_index do |i|             
        $ranWordBool[i] = false         
      end           

      system "cls"          
      gameLoop
      input = gets.chomp
      shouldQuit(input) 
    end
```

Comment: https://github.com/GlobalNamesArchitecture/damerau-levenshtein and/or Google by “Damerau-Levenstein distance” and “Jaro-Winkler distance.”

Comment: @max as I said I am fairly new but I will look more into that

Comment: What you are looking for is something like the levenshtein distance which gives a number of the likeness betweeen two strings.

Comment: Not quite. I want to return feedback based on how close they are to guessing the correct random word. I dont want to use any kinds of APIs just standard Ruby features @max

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
# Picking random word to guess
word = ['open', 'real', 'hang', 'mice'].sample

loop do
  puts "So, guess the word:"

  input_word = gets.strip
  if word == input_word
    puts("You are right, the word is: #{input_word}")
    break
  end

  puts "You typed: #{input_word}"

  # Split both the word to guess and the suggested word into array of letters
  word_in_letters  = word.split('')
  input_in_letters = input_word.split('')

  result = []
  # Iterate over each letter in the word to guess
  word_in_letters.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    # Pick the corresponding letter in the entered word
    letter_from_input = input_in_letters[index]

    if letter == letter_from_input
      result << "#{letter_from_input} - Correct"
      next
    end

    # Take nearby letters by nearby indexes
    # `reject` is here to skip negative indexes
    # ie: letter 'i' in a word "mice"
    #   this will return 'm' and 'c'
    # ie: letter 'm' in a word "mice"
    #   this will return 'i'
    letters_around =
      [index - 1, index + 1]
      .reject { |i| i < 0 }
      .map { |i| word_in_letters[i] }
    if letters_around.include?(letter_from_input)
      result << "#{letter_from_input} - Close"
      next
    end

    result << "#{letter_from_input} - Incorrect"
  end

  puts result.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: Yes but close doesnt quite work @nattfodd. For instance if the word was hang and I typed in ngha then I would get 

close, close, close, close

Comment: So please specify - what behavior do you expect from "close" message to the letter?